# How do I access Info1 through the Bachelor struct and the Info struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I' ve tried various instructions and at the end there are two different errors:

1. `deferencing pointer to incomplete type(error in this code)`
2. `request for member 'Info1' in something not a structure or union`

I've already read about this error here at stackoverflow, but I don' t get it. This is my first question ever, so please answer, how I get there and why I get there this way. Just look at the main and the else-block.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define DEFAULT 4.0

typedef struct _info {
   double Info1;
   double Info2;
   double Info3;
   double TI;
   double Softec;
   double Prog;
   double Sofpro;
   double DB;
   double SysInf;
   double KomSym;
} Info;

typedef struct _math
{
   double Ana1;
   double Lina1;
   double DS;
   double Logik;
} Mathe;


typedef struct _nb {
   double Ana2;
   double Lina2;
   double Sto1;
   double Opt1;
} NB;

typedef struct _bsc {
   struct Info *info;
   struct Mathe *mathe;
   struct NB *nb;
   double Wahl1;
   double Wahl2;
   double Praxis;
   double Sem;
   double BSC;
} Bachelor;

int main() {
   Bachelor * dima;
   dima = malloc(sizeof(Bachelor));
   if(dima == NULL) {
      free(dima);
      return 1;
   } else {
      (dima->info)->Info1 = DEFAULT;        //error is here
      printf("Dima got it!\n");
      printf("Info1: %f\n",(dima->info)->Info1);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error? This `if(dima == NULL) { free(dima);` is not a problem, but you don't need to `free()` if you didn't `malloc()` successfuly.

Comment: That was not the question. Look in the else-block. I am trying to set/access  Info1 in the Bachelor struct though the Info struct

Comment: it was not visible what the error was because of your question's formatting. Is this code the exact code? did you copy every thing?

Comment: Can you please add a comment were you copy everything what you can see from my question, because I don' t know what you don't see?!

Comment: this error doesn't make sense unless you have something else in your actual code that cases the problem.

Comment: but why is the Info struct incomplete? what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you don't have a `struct Info` defined anywhere, so the definition of `struct _bsc` is wrong, to fix it remove the `struct` or use the `struct` name, i.e. `_info_`, like this

```
typedef struct _bsc {
    Info *info;
/* ^ no struct here */
    Mathe *mathe;
/* ^ no struct here */
    NB *nb;
/* ^ no struct here */
    double Wahl1;
    double Wahl2;
    double Praxis;
    double Sem;
    double BSC;
} Bachelor;
```

---

Or:

---

```
typedef struct _bsc {
    struct _info *info;
    struct _math *mathe;
    struct _nb *nb;
    double Wahl1;
    double Wahl2;
    double Praxis;
    double Sem;
    double BSC;
} Bachelor;
```

You should also allocate space for the `info`, `mathe` and `nb` fields of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and effort, that did the trick

Answer (score 2):

Your initial initialization of `dima` is correct:

```
Bachelor* dima = malloc(sizeof(Bachelor));
```

However, your statement:

```
dima->Info->Info1 = DEAULT;
```

Is wrong. `dima` has memory allocated, but for each pointer within the struct, you'll likely need to assign or allocate memory to it.

Do something along the lines of :

```
dima->info = malloc(sizeof(struct Info));
```

Feel free to ask for more info. In short, C does NOTHING for you automatically. It expects your code to be very explicit (ie: a strong typed as opposed to a dynamically typed language). Now would be a good time to read up on the topic of "constructors" in C++, just to be sure that you are using the right language for the task. I use C for low-level and performance-focused code, but C++ for massive non-CPU-intensive projects IRL.

Good luck!

Comment: You are right: dima->Info->Info1 = DEAULT; is the error and I know that. How can I get to Info1? I'm using C, because I have an exam in C soon.

Comment: First of all `dima` does not have an `Info` field, it's `info`, second that is not the problem.

Comment: error: dereferencing pointer to an incomplete type ==> why is my Info struct an incomplete type?